# Force web browser to download entire page contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser

I have a large web page file (around 10mb) on a server drive that is accessible throughout the network.  Not everyone will copy this to their local computer before opening it, which would make it a lot faster.  Since not everyone will do this, I have to find out how to preload the entire contents of the web page into their browser.  At the moment it is only downloading the active chunks (visible ones) and when needed it will request the other sections as they are requested from the jquery hides and shows.  It is taking too long though.  What can I do to make the web browser get the entire page before displaying it?

Thanks

Comment: What parts of the page are not being downloaded to the browser? Is it something that gets pulled with ajax or images or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/octet-stream" />
```